# Attempting to transfer erc20 elrond to elrond gold in trust wallet - error insufficient funds

Tags: transactions, blockchain, tokens, erc-20, transfer

Does anyone have a step by step guide to transfer my 7566 elrond to elrond gold?

My elrond is in Trust Wallet and tried to send to my elrond gold wallet but network said I have insufficient funds and the charge was about $54.

I'm sure this charge is too high and 7566 elrond must be worth 7.56 elrond gold if you divide by 1000.

Any help or a step by step guide would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have enough ETH in your wallet to pay for the transaction. In a normal situation it wouldn't have costed that much to send tokens but since the network usage is high right now, the tx fee is also high.

You can check etherscan to see the gas price required for your transaction to go through: https://etherscan.io/gastracker